# Python pass request headers to pdfkit

Tags: python, pdf, pdf-generation, html, python-pdfkit

I am trying to convert a URL to pdf using pdfkit in python as follows.

```
import pdfkit
pdfkit.from_url(url, file_path)
```

I wanted to know is there some way to pass custom request headers with this URL such as `X-Proxy-REMOTE-USER` to something.

Answer (score 1):

[`python-pdfkit`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfkit) is just a wrapper around [`wkhtmltopdf`](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/). Looking at the fifth example from the [usage section of the docs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfkit#usage) there's a third parameter that you can specify for additional options:

```
options = {
    'page-size': 'Letter',
    'margin-top': '0.75in',
    'margin-right': '0.75in',
    'margin-bottom': '0.75in',
    'margin-left': '0.75in',
    'encoding': "UTF-8",
    'no-outline': None
}

pdfkit.from_url('http://google.com', 'out.pdf', options=options)
```

The [options are specified here](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt) and you are specifically interest in `--custom-header <name> <value>`. Unfortunately they don't say how to pass an option that takes multiple parameters but since the command line wants a space between the two and looking at the code they don't appear to be changing the value parameter I'd try just passing the `name` and `value` as the value of the option with a space between the two.

```
options = {
    'custom-header': 'X-Proxy-REMOTE-USER STEVE'
}

pdfkit.from_url('http://google.com', 'out.pdf', options=options)
```

Comment: Now I get this error `IOError: wkhtmltopdf exited with non-zero code 1. error:
You need to specify at least one input file, and exactly one output file
Use - for stdin or stdout`

Comment: You might need to inspect the actual HTTP headers that are being sent and received, maybe test on a local server and just dump them to disk.

Comment: @ChrisHaas, the format you suggest results in the error reported by @station. The correct format is `'custom-header': [('x-header-name', 'header-value')]`. From here: https://github.com/JazzCore/python-pdfkit/issues/45

Comment: Thanks @John! Support for that was added 9 months after I wrote this answer. If that is indeed the way to do it (which it definitely looks like it is) it might be valuable to have a dedicated answer written for it.